# bootbox.dialog compile error in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, bootbox

I'm trying to user `Bootbox` Custom Dialog with `bootbox.d.ts`. It fails to compile.

```
bootbox.dialog({
  message: "I am a custom dialog",
  buttons: {
    success: {
      label: "Success!",
      className: "btn-success",
      callback: function() {
        Example.show("great success");
      }
    },
    danger: {
      label: "Danger!",
      className: "btn-danger",
      callback: function() {
        Example.show("uh oh, look out!");
      }
    },
    main: {
      label: "Click ME!",
      className: "btn-primary",
      callback: function() {
        Example.show("Primary button");
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Error:

> Error 49  Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call
>   target:   Could not apply type 'string' to argument 1 which is of type
>   '{ message: string; buttons: { cancel: { label: string; className:
>   string; }; confirmDelete: { label: string; className: string;
>   callback: () => void; }; }; }'.

bootbox.d.ts:

```
interface BootboxStatic {
    alert(message: string, callback: () => void): void;
    alert(message: string, customButtonText?: string, callback?: () => void): void;
    confirm(message: string, callback: (result: boolean) => void): void;
    confirm(message: string, cancelButtonText?: string, confirmButtonText?: string, callback?: (result: boolean) => void): void;
    prompt(message: string, callback: (result: string) => void, defaultValue?: string): void;
    prompt(message: string, cancelButtonText?: string, confirmButtonText?: string, callback?: (result: string) => void, defaultValue?: string): void;
    dialog(message: string, handlers: BootboxHandler[], options?: any): void;
    dialog(message: string, handler: BootboxHandler): void;
    dialog(message: string): void;
    hideAll(): void;
    animate(shouldAnimate: boolean): void;
    backdrop(backdropValue: string): void;
    classes(customCssClasses: string): void;
    setIcons(icons: BootboxIcons): void;
    setLocale(localeName: string): void;
    addLocale(localeName: string, translations: BootboxLocale) : void;
}
```

How can I modify the definitions to accept the dialog with the parameter I'm using?

Answer (score 0):

I got it sorted. Had to add the line

`dialog(options: any): void; // Had to add this line`

to bootbox.d.ts:

```
interface BootboxStatic {
    alert(message: string, callback: () => void): void;
    alert(message: string, customButtonText?: string, callback?: () => void): void;
    confirm(message: string, callback: (result: boolean) => void): void;
    confirm(message: string, cancelButtonText?: string, confirmButtonText?: string, callback?: (result: boolean) => void): void;
    prompt(message: string, callback: (result: string) => void, defaultValue?: string): void;
    prompt(message: string, cancelButtonText?: string, confirmButtonText?: string, callback?: (result: string) => void, defaultValue?: string): void;
    dialog(message: string, handlers: BootboxHandler[], options?: any): void;
    dialog(message: string, handler: BootboxHandler): void;
    dialog(message: string): void;
    dialog(options: any): void; // Had to add this line
    hideAll(): void;
    animate(shouldAnimate: boolean): void;
    backdrop(backdropValue: string): void;
    classes(customCssClasses: string): void;
    setIcons(icons: BootboxIcons): void;
    setLocale(localeName: string): void;
    addLocale(localeName: string, translations: BootboxLocale) : void; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use BootboxHandler array

```
dialog(message: string, handlers: BootboxHandler[], options?: any): void;

interface BootboxHandler {
    label: string;
    class: string;
    callback: (result?: any) => void;
}
```

Change your code for :

```
bootbox.dialog("I am a custom dialog",
  [{
      label: "Success!",
      class: "btn-success",
      callback: function() {
        Example.show("great success");
      }
    },
    {
      label: "Danger!",
      class: "btn-danger",
      callback: function() {
        Example.show("uh oh, look out!");
      }
    },
    {
      label: "Click ME!",
      class: "btn-primary",
      callback: function() {
        Example.show("Primary button");
      }
    }
  }]
 );
```